# Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e IN ALL IE VERSION

Tags: html, ajax

I have used ajax functionality for pagination.This functionality is working fine in other browser(FF,CHROME) accept IE BROWSER.I am getting error for this following line as Error on this line .

Thanx in Advance

```
if (req) {
  var th = this;
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var s = req.readyState;
    if (s == 4) {
      // Avoid memory leak by removing closure.
      req.onreadystatechange = th.dummy;
      // Remove possible junk from response.
      var responseText = req.responseText;//Error on this line
      try {
        // Call associated dataReady().
        eval(responseText);
      } catch (e) {
        Subsys_JsHttpRequest_Js.dataReady(id, "JavaScript code generated by backend is invalid!\n"+responseText, null);
      }
    } else {
      th.readyState = s;
      if (th.onreadystatechange) th.onreadystatechange()
    }
  };

  this._id = id;
}
```

Comment: @Jimmy: Give him answer instead of commenting on my edit. :-) I edited so people could read it better, so maybe he would get help faster. The fact I edited doesn't mean I know the answer to the question.

Comment: ok i appreciate u ken white...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Microsoft's description of the error message](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;304625&x=10&y=13) as one related to encoding, set appropriate encoding on the AJAX output on the server side.

Comment: It is a parsing error.  If you're using XML, it is likely encoding (please read the article... many common encoding schemes aren't allowed).

If you're using JSON, you've probably got invalid JSON (single quotes, unquoted keys, or rogue commas).

Without seeing your actual output code and/or monitoring the actual encoding of the endpoint, there is little else the community can do.