# IE9: AngularJS Causes "SCRIPT58734: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e"

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9

I think this is caused by routing in angularJS. Points to:

angular.min.js, line 78 chacter 453.

There's also a problem with relative JS/CSS files that start with same value as  having "http: ///" prefixed.

The more I experiment with the issue, the more it seems like an AngularJS UI Router issue. Error occurs after calling $state.go('some_view').

UPDATE #1:
Doing more digging around, the error seems to point at an encoding issue. Debugging the code, the error is triggered soon after the router attempts to load in a template. In IE9, the response header for the Content Type of the template is text/html;chartset=utf8. Some posts have pointed that it needs to be utf=8 with a dash.

Have not been able to change the encoding yet.

UPDATE #2:
Changed the default charset for nginx from utf8 to utf-8 and it fixed the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e IN ALL IE VERSION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000509/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-c00ce56e-in-all-ie-version)